# How to fit with column to content

Tags: ag-grid

I need to fit the column width to the content of the column and allow scrolling horizontally.

I am using ag-grid with JavaScript

exist a way to do this? I always fund example using gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit() but this will fit to the grid.

any help link?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/

Answer (score 3):

Use `columnApi.autoSizeColumns()` not `api.sizeColumnsToFit()`